# iOS 6 Facebook 'The operation couldn't be completed.'

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

ERROR-->I am trying to Login with Facebook with IOS6.0

Ocassionary, users receive this error message particularly those who do
not turn on Facebook on their device.

Any idea why would it happen on some IOS6 device and some not?

```
- (void)openSession
{
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"email",
                        @"user_birthday",
                        nil];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your Facebook app has not the right bundle id. [check this](http://kosovich.org.ua/tmp/facebook_ios6_app_howto.png)

Comment: only happened to some users. not all.